# FFC 12 pin cable with a USB interface

Tags: usb, modules, cable

I have [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1D-CCD-Scan-Engine-Barcode-scanner-work-with-Arduino-Rapberry-Pi-embedded-module-engine/32825168672.html?spm=a2g0s.12269583.0.0.1cb3cd96fYVG45) barcode scanner module and I need to connect it to my raspberry pi 3 b+. I am a beginner at this and I don't know how to go about it. I have been searching for weeks. The seller in aliexpress has no documentation or anything whatsoever. I bought [this](https://www.amazon.de/flaches-d%C3%BCnnes-Standard-Synchronisierung-Aufladung-Black/dp/B075R6Q3GL)also, so that I can connect the barcode scanner ffc cable with the USB interface then to plug it in the raspberry pi. But this cable is bigger than 12 pins so it didn't work out. Any sort of guidance will help me tremendously.

Edit: [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Low-power-consumption-2D-scan-Engine-work-with-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi-E3000H-serial-port-command-Manual/32896999662.html?spm=2114.10010108.1000014.1.724d35e3ecoaPJ&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.13338.128418.0&scm_id=1007.13338.128418.0&scm-url=1007.13338.128418.0&pvid=51e132e3-f4d9-4ed8-aaa1-af94f2e1d86e) is another similar product but which explains the interface specs of the barcode scanner module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the time has come to find another barcode scanner?  The core problem is the lack of interface specs for the scanner.  This means the Raspberry Pi is irrelevant and the question is off topic.

Comment: Hello, that [second scanner](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Low-power-consumption-2D-scan-Engine-work-with-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi-E3000H-serial-port-command-Manual/32896999662.html?spm=2114.10010108.1000014.1.724d35e3ecoaPJ&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.13338.128418.0&scm_id=1007.13338.128418.0&scm-url=1007.13338.128418.0&pvid=51e132e3-f4d9-4ed8-aaa1-af94f2e1d86e) has a development board available that looks like it pulls the lines out to some 0.1" headers and a couple of USB sockets. Should get you up and running.